# How can I read a URL without using urlib2.urlopen in Python?

Tags: python, json, django, facebook

I've been reading and displaying a Facebook Graph api url form the Facebook Graph API like this:

```
facebook_info = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/%s/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email&access_token=" % settings.FACEBOOK_API_VERSION + access_token)
facebook_info = facebook_info.read()
return facebook_info
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this in Python I was thinking something like Request.get(...). Where I don't use urllib2.urlopen and the the '+' sign to concatenate.

Comment: Is `urlopen` the problem, or the construction of the URL? The `urllib2` has tools to construct URLs in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although `requests` library is excellent and recommended for its ease of use, I don't think using `requests.get` will be inherently **better** in this case. Your code seems fine and will work perfectly for what it does. Why do you want to change it? Style?

Or you want to build the url in a more clear way, perhaps?

```
url_template = "https://graph.facebook.com/{api_version}/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email&access_token={token}"

url = url_template.format(
    api_version=settings.FACEBOOK_API_VERSION,
    token=access_token,
)

facebook_info = requests.get(url).json()
return facebook_info
```

Comment: How would it be done even if it's not better or worse?